# How to bind s parameter of scatter function in matplotlib to number of occurences of coordinates in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
df.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', s=50)
```

I want size of markers to reflect frequency of coordinates occurences in dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list (e.g. using `s=df['column']`) to to the `s` key word to size the scatter markers according to those values.

See the last [example in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot).

Comment: did this answer your question after all?